# Grounding with portable using interlock

Tags: electrical

Was a similar question; but they were not using a interlock.  I have a DuroStar dual fuel DS 10000eh that is hooked up to my main breaker using a 50 amp plug and using an interlock set up.  My panel does have surge protection breaker, but there is nothing being grounded from the generator. Am I protected via my panel surge protectors or do I need to install a 8 ft grounding rod and run a4 4 awg(200 amp panel) from that to my generator. Ty kindly for your feedback.

Comment: I've read this twice now and I'm still confused. It might help if you were to [edit] in more details. Also, I think your first sentence refers to another question, it would be helpful if you provided a link to the question instead of asking others to guess about it - that would probably provide some background.

Answer (score 1):

The neutral-ground bond on your generator needs to be removed when plugged into the house.

Once this is done, and assuming the installation was done properly, the house's ground rods will ground the generator.

Of course there are 1000 ways to do a generator wrong and kill people.  It is the #1 way people die in hurricanes.